# ¿Como modificar y actualizar simultáneamente las filas de un ListView en ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview

Buen día, tengo un `ListView` conectado a una `SQLDataSource` y deseo que todas las filas puedan ser editadas simultáneamente y con un botón actualizar todas las filas. He intentado poner controles que puedan ser editados en el `ItemTemplate` y poner un botón con el siguiente código:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To ListView.Items.Count - 1
     ListView.UpdateItem(i, False)
Next
```

Al ejecutarlo, me actualiza solamente la primer fila y se pierden las modificaciones de las siguientes filas.

Answer (score 1):

Buen día, he resuelto mi problema, el código:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To ListView.Items.Count - 1
     ListView.UpdateItem(i, False)
Next
```

funciona correctamente, en mi caso el problema era generado por una instrucción en el evento `OnUpdateItem` del `ListView`

Gracias. Espero sea de utilidad para la comunidad de stackoverflow el código proporcionado.